# What use is @TestInstance annotation in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

Can you give a simple explanation of `@TestInstance` annotation and how it is useful in JUnit 5?

I think we can achieve the same effect probably by **making our fields *`static`***.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think [the docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle) provide a useful summary:

> If you would prefer that JUnit Jupiter execute all test methods on the same test instance, simply annotate your test class with @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS). When using this mode, a new test instance will be created once per test class. Thus, if your test methods rely on state stored in instance variables, you may need to reset that state in @BeforeEach or @AfterEach methods.
>
> The "per-class" mode has some additional benefits over the default "per-method" mode. Specifically, with the "per-class" mode it becomes possible to declare @BeforeAll and @AfterAll on non-static methods as well as on interface default methods. The "per-class" mode therefore also makes it possible to use @BeforeAll and @AfterAll methods in @Nested test classes.

But you've probably read that already and you are correct in thinking that making a field static will have the same effect as declaring the field as an instance variable and using `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`.

So, perhaps the answer to the question "how it could be useful in JUnit 5" is that using a `@TestInstance` ...

- Is explicit about your intentions. It could be assumed that use of the static keyword was accidental whereas use of `@TestInstance` is less likely to be accidental or a result of thoughless copy-n-paste.
- Delegates the responsibility for managing scope and lifecycle and clean up to the framework rather than having to remember to manage that yourself.

Comment: It is also a pre-requisite if you want to create Parametrised tests with MethodSource inside Nested test classes
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1229

Comment: Making test class members static can be problematic with class hierarchies. Polymorphism gives you some cool options to write cleaner and less redundant code. `@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)` should be the default in Jupiter IMHO. It results in better and more elastic test code and has nothing but advantages in comparison to the alternative.

Answer (score 38):

This annotation was introduced to reduce the number of objects created when running your unit tests.

Adding `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` to your test class will avoid that a new instance of your class is created for every test in the class.
This is particulary usefull when you have a lot of tests in the same test class and the instantiation of this class is expensive.

This annotation should be used with caution. All unit tests should be isolated and independent of eachother. If one of the tests changes the state of the test class then you should not use this feature.

Making your fields static to achieve the same effect is not a good idea. It will indeed reduce the number of objects created but they cannot be cleaned up when all tests in the test class are executed. This can cause problems when you have a giant test suite.

Comment: I like this answer because it directly addresses a major downside of using static fields.

Comment: @dyVeloper What will be the similar annotation in testng?

Answer (score 15):

[`@TestInstance`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.html) is used to configure the *lifecycle of test instances* for the annotated test class or test interface:

- [`PER_CLASS`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.Lifecycle.html#PER_CLASS): A new test instance will be created once per test class.
- [`PER_METHOD`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.Lifecycle.html#PER_METHOD): A new test instance will be created for each test method, test factory method, or test template method. This mode is analogous to the behavior found in JUnit versions 1 through 4.

If [`@TestInstance`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.html) is not explicitly declared on a test class or on a test interface implemented by a test class, the lifecycle mode will implicitly default to [`PER_METHOD`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.Lifecycle.html#PER_METHOD).

---

Setting the test instance lifecycle mode to [`PER_CLASS`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.Lifecycle.html#PER_CLASS) enables the following features:

- Shared test instance state between test methods in a given test class as well as between non-static `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` methods in the test class.
- Declaration of `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` methods in `@Nested` test classes.
- Declaration of `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` on interface default methods.
- Simplified declaration of `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` methods in test classes implemented with the Kotlin programming language.

See the [test instance lifecycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle) documentation for further details.

Answer (score 8):

since no one provide a proper coding example, I would like to give a simple code sample as below to understand the concept,

**Per Method Sample - Default Option in Junit5**
Note two methods are static, otherwise it will fire an exception because class instantiate in each method.

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
public class MathUtilTestPerMethod {

    MathUtil util;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAllInit() {
        System.out.println("running before all");
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAllCleanUp() {
        System.out.println("running after all");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        util = new MathUtil();
        System.out.println("running before each...");
    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println("running after each...");
    }

    @Test
    void testSum() {
        assertEquals(2, util.addtwoNumbers(1, 1));
    }

}
```

**Per Class Sample**
Note that static is removed from the two methods and MathUtil object is created globally not in a method, because class instantiate only once.

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MathUtilTestPerClass {

    MathUtil util = new MathUtil();

    @BeforeAll
    void beforeAllInit() {
        System.out.println("running before all");
    }

    @AfterAll
    void afterAllCleanUp() {
        System.out.println("running after all");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        System.out.println("running before each...");
    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println("running after each...");
    }

    @Test
    void testSum() {
        assertEquals(2, util.addtwoNumbers(1, 1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for hint about static removal from methods annotated by BeforeAll and AfterAll

Answer (score 3):

This is also useful when writing tests in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) (because it doesn't have static methods).

So, instead of using a companion object with `@JvmStatic` funs in it for `@BeforeAll` or `@AfterAll`, make the lifecycle `PER_CLASS` and annotate regular methods with `@BeforeAll` or `@AfterAll`:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTest {

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        println("I am invoked only once")
    }
}
```

In addition, it also makes it possible to use simple class methods as factory functions for `@MethodSource` in parameterized tests (instead of wrapping the factory function in `companion object {}` and marking the factory function with `@JvmStatic`):

```kotlin
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("generateStrings")
fun `Test strings`(argument: String) {
    check(argument.isNotEmpty())
}
private fun generateStrings() = listOf(
    "java",
    "kotlin"
)
```

<sup>When using this approach, be careful to reset your instance variables in `@BeforeEach` or `@AfterEach` funs if necessary.</sup>

Thanks to [this article](https://www.arhohuttunen.com/junit-5-kotlin/) for its help.