# How do I set up a Spring Data Neo4j integration test with JUnit 5 (in Kotlin)?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-test, junit5

Most examples around the Web for doing Spring integration tests with Neo4j are still on JUnit 4, and use the Neo4jRule.

How do we create a setup for Neo4j + Spring + JUnit 5?

Answer (score 4):

If you are testing on embedded, please use the Test Harness with a simple Spring Configuration.

Here are some examples:

https://medium.com/neo4j/testing-your-neo4j-based-java-application-34bef487cc3c

https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-sdn-ogm-tips/tree/master/examples/using-the-test-harness
https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-sdn-ogm-tips/tree/master/examples/using-testcontainers

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter/tree/master/examples/testing-with-neo4j-harness

I would have an eye on the above ^^
This and test containers will be our way forward.

Note: The @Neo4jExtension is mostly used internally by the core team and not recommended for general use.

Comment: Michael, is it still true that Neo4jExtension is not recommended? I'm asking because this feels like it contradicts _"Support for official testing support classes. From 4.0 onwards, Neo4j provides a set of Junit 4 rules and Junit 5 extensions for community and enterprise users."_ from https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/migration/surface-changes/java-api/